# How to access type of functions generics?

Tags: typescript

Assume a library exposes function like this

```
export function getData<Data extends BaseData>(dataPath: string) {
 // Do work
}
```

If I import this function, is there any way I can access and store type of it's generic (`Data extends BaseData`) bit inside my own `type MyType` value, to reference it latter on?

Current issue I am facing is that `BaseData` from the library is not exported, thus I can't really use it (worst case I can replicate it, but I am wondering if there is more cleaner solution, something like `ReturnType` util, but for this constraint / generic)

Comment: Actually store the constraint? You cannot store a constraint in a type.

Comment: You _can_ get _what_ it extends, if the generic type is used on a parameter and you know which parameter. `type Get<T> = T extends (param: infer Param) => void ? Param : never; type Foo = Get<typeof getData>;` Assuming `getData<Data extends Something>(data: Data)`

Comment: @DarrylNoakes any chance you could expand on this in an answer? Current issue I am facing is that `BaseData` from the library is not exported, thus I can't really use it (worst case I can replicate it, but I am wondering if there is more cleaner sollution, something like `ReturnType`, but for this constraint / generic)

Comment: `function getData<Data extends BaseData>(dataPath: string)` takes in a `string` and returns `void`; it's completely independent of `Data` and therefore `BaseData`, so there's no structural way to infer this.  Is that really a representative example?  A [mre] shouldn't be *too* minimal or there's not enough information to use.  Maybe it's more like `getData<Data extends BaseData)(data: Data)`?  Maybe it returns a value related to `Data`?  Something that gives us a handle on `BaseData`?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes your Get util works, if you post it as answer I'll accept it

Comment: So there must be someway to get a handle on that generic, as @jcalz says? I'll write up an answer.

Comment: After @DarrylNoakes posts the answer, OP should please [edit] the code in the question so that it matches.  Presumably `(data: Data)` (which depends on `Data`) and not `(dataPath: string)` (which doesn't).

Comment: @jcalz I don't think that is relevant, this `Data` type can be used elsewhere in the function i.e. as type for one of the return field of an object.

Comment: It's definitely relevant whether the call signature depends or does not depend on the generic type parameter.  Your current example doesn't show any return type at all, so it's too minimal to be reproducible.  You should either edit the example so the call signature depends on `Data` in some way (either the parameter types or the return type or both) or you should wait until the answer you asked for is posted and adjust your example so that it matches.  If you leave it like this the answer is "it's impossible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming that the generic is used somewhere where you can use `infer` on it** (i.e., in the parameter list or return type), you can get the type it extends.
If it is not used in one of those places, *there is no way to get it*.
E.g., there is no way to get the `BaseData` from `getData<Data extends BaseData>()`.

I'll assume there is a function `getData` defined as follows:

```
declare function getData<Data extends BaseData>(data: Data): any;
```

You now have two options: you can create your own generic to extract the type, or you can use `Parameters`.

```
// Using `Parameters` and the index of the parameter you need.
type FromParam1 = Parameters<typeof getData>[0]; // BaseData

// Using a custom generic.
type TypeOfParam<T> = T extends (param: infer Param) => void ? Param : never;

type FromParam2 = TypeOfParam<typeof getData>; // BaseData
```

The custom generic is useful if the type you want is wrapped in other types:

```
declare function getData<Data extends BaseData>(
  data: Record<string, Data>
): any;

type TypeOfParam<T> = T extends (param: Record<string, infer Param>) => void
  ? Param
  : never;

type FromParam = TypeOfParam<typeof getData>; // BaseData
```

If the type is in the return type, you can get it using the same principles.